# how to understand rename{ old = "temp.lua", new = "temp1.lua" }?

Tags: lua

I'm playing with this lua link: http://underpop.free.fr/l/lua/docs/programming-in-lua-first-edition.pdf and get confused about the rename function. I tried it out and only to get an error message as the following.

```
> rename{old = "temp.lua", new = "temp1.lua"}
stdin:1: attempt to call global 'rename' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
> os.rename{old = "temp.lua", new = "temp1.lua"}
stdin:1: bad argument #1 to 'rename' (string expected, got table)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'rename'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Moreover, I'm learning Lua because I'm reading a piece of code, which is written in Lua. I do not think the link provided above, programming in lua first edition, is a good tutorial. I've also found a reference menu, but do not quite like it also. Can anyone please provide a good tutorial based on your opinion?

**EDIT:** I tried it again with the following code:

```
> function rename(arg)
>>   return os.rename(arg.old, arg.new)
>> end
> 
> rename{old = "temp.lua", new = "temp1.lua"}
```

It works this time.

Comment: Have you defined `rename` as a function anywhere?

Comment: No. From the link, I think rename is from the os library.

Comment: Please don't be impatient.  Read [the text](https://www.lua.org/pil/5.3.html) before trying to run the code.  The text is absolutely understandable.

Comment: > function rename(arg)
>>   return os.rename(arg.old, arg.new)
>> end
> 
> rename{old = "temp.lua", new = "temp1.lua"}

Comment: Yes, that is the exact function.

Comment: Move your edit to an answer

Answer (score 2):

```
stdin:1: attempt to call global 'rename' (a nil value)
```

This error message tells you exactly what the problem is.

It is caused by this line:

```
rename{old = "temp.lua", new = "temp1.lua"}
```

`rename` is a nil value. Hence Lua does not know what to do if you call it. In order to avoid this error you have to define rename as a callable variable like.

Let me just quote the tutorial you do not find good.

> ```
> rename{old="temp.lua", new="temp1.lua"}
> ```
>
> Accordingly, **we define rename** with only one parameter and get the
>   actual arguments from this parameter:
>
> ```
> function rename (arg)
>    return os.rename(arg.old, arg.new)
> end
> ```

Comment: Thank you. I was just a bit confused with the use of "{ }" and "( )" to call a function earlier. I have already edited my question.

Comment: @kkxx Lua Manual: "A call of the form f{fields} is syntactic sugar for f({fields}); that is, the argument list is a single new table."
    Programming in Lua: "If
the function has one single argument and this argument is either a literal string or a table
constructor, then the parentheses are optional"

Please read more carefully!